# How to set a linear background color of a container from left to right, but only cover the half top of the container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a container that has LinearGradient as its background but with these constraints:

- The linear gradient is from left to right
- The linear gradient color only covers the half top of the container

As shown in the image below, what I want to build is this.

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
...
Widget build(context) {
  return Container( // 1. Outer container (black border box in image)
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [//color1, //color2],
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.centerRight,
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Container( // 2. Inner container (colored white in image)
        // some padding and decoration for border-radius
      ),
    )
  )
}
...
```

But what it does is the gradient color covering all of the outer container (what I want is only half the top of the outer container). Is it possible to do this? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Does the bottom half need to be transparent or do you want to set a color to it?

Comment: The bottom half needs to be white. But I think transparent is also okay (since the scaffold background color white will set it to white).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[image]

```dart
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Colors.pink.shade700,
        Colors.pink.shade300,
      ],
      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
      end: Alignment.centerRight,
    ),
  ),
  child: DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
      gradient: const LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Colors.white,
          Colors.transparent,
        ],
        begin: Alignment(0, 0),
        end: Alignment(0, -0.01),
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 70,
        width: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```